# awk to compare multiple columns in 2 files

Tags: awk, file-comparison

I would like to compare multiple columns from 2 files and NOT print lines matching my criteria.
An example of this would be:

file1

```
apple  green  4
orange  red  5
apple  yellow 6
apple  yellow 8
grape  green 5
```

file2

```
apple  yellow 7
grape  green 10
```

output

```
apple  green  4
orange  red  5
apple  yellow 8
```

I want to remove lines where `$1` and `$2` from `file1` correspond to `$1` and `$2` from `file2` AND when `$3` from `file1` is smaller than `$3` from `file2`.
I can now only do the first part of the job, that is remove lines where `$1` and `$2` from `file1` correspond to `$1` and `$2` from `file2` (fields are separated by tabs):

```
awk -F '\t' 'FNR == NR {a[$1FS$2]=$1; next} !($1FS$2 in a)' file2 file1
```

Could you help me apply the last condition?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are after is this:

```
awk '(NR==FNR){a[$1,$2]=$3; next}!(($1,$2) in a) && a[$1,$2] < $3))' <file2> <file1>
```

Comment: When you're using the same hard-coded set of values as a key in multiple locations, seriously consider using a variable to hold the key instead: `'{key=$1 FS $2} (NR==FNR){a[key]=$3; next}!(key in a) && a[key] < $3))'`. Makes life easier if/when you need to change the key and IMHO improves clarity.

Comment: It works but I had to remove the last two parentheses:

Comment: @Agathe Which parenthesis?

Comment: It works but I had to remove the last two parentheses:
`awk '(NR==FNR){a[$1,$2]=$3; next}!(($1,$2) in a) && a[$1,$2] < $3' <file2> <file1>`
Also, can I ask for an explanation of the code? Especially, I do not understand the `a[key]=$3` and `a[key]<$3` parts. If I understand right, you are creating an array called `a` in which you store `$1FS$2` (=`key`) from file 2 and then you look for `$1FS$2` in file 1 to not print it. However, why does it seem you are assigning the array or comparing it to a column `$3`?

Comment: @Agathe `a[key]` means the element of array `a` with index `key`. So `a[key]=$3` means to store the value of `$3` in the array-element `a[key]` . The statement `key in a` is query that checks if array `a` has an element with index `key`

Answer (score 3):

Store 3rd field value while building the array and then use it for comparison

```
$ awk -F '\t' 'FNR==NR{a[$1FS$2]=$3; next} !(($1FS$2 in a) && $3 > a[$1FS$2])' f2 f1
apple   green   4
orange  red 5
apple   yellow  6
grape   green   5
```

Better written as:

```
awk -F '\t' '{k = $1FS$2} FNR==NR{a[k]=$3; next} !((k in a) && $3 > a[k])' f2 f1
```

Comment: The fieldseparator is not needed as `awk` uses blanks by default (including tabs)

Comment: true, just in case someone reading the answer in future has fields separated by tabs but fields can contain spaces ;)